# How to load a tensorflow model in gpu in a java project

Tags: java, tensorflow, gpu

**I am trying to run a java project that loads tensorflow model for object detection.How to run this project in gpu.**

**My system has NVIDIA graphics card and have already switched to the same.Also CUDA has been successfully installed.I have already run this in cpu.Now I want to switch to gpu.**

**To switch to GPU, the following configurations were added.But failed to switch to GPU.**

```
ConfigProto configproto = ConfigProto.newBuilder()
            .setAllowSoftPlacement(true)                 
            .setGpuOptions(GPUOptions.newBuilder()
            .setPerProcessGpuMemoryFraction(0.01).build())
            .build();

SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.loader(modeldir).withTags("serve").withConfigProto(configproto.toByteArray()).load()
```

**I expect the model to run in GPU.But the obtained result is as follows**

> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.652043: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31]
>   Reading SavedModel from: /saved_model
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.686901: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54]
>   Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.699563: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.704712: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
>   2712000000 Hz
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.704847: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service
>   0x7f6cf036be50 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.704862: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): ,
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.759224: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:182]
>   Restoring SavedModel bundle.
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.759280: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:192]
>   The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were
>   restored. File does not exist: /saved_model/variables/variables.index
>
> 2019-06-28 14:50:25.759291: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:285]
>   SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 107259
>   microseconds.

Comment: Make sure you installed GPU driver properly: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: Even after installing the GPU driver and adding the libtensorflow_jni_gpu dependency  to the project's pom.xml , tensorflow is stilling running on cpu.

Comment: 2019-07-02 10:29:13.520206: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-07-02 10:29:13.525238: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2712000000 Hz